# Ionic: jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keystore, keytool, jarsigner

I'm using ionic for developing an android app. I jarsigned my app by mistake with an new keystore. As I got the error that the certifikate is unequal by uploading the app to the play store I used my backup keystore file with the same certificate needed in playstore.

Now if I want to jarsign my .apk with the command

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore app-release-unsigned.apk MyApp.apk alias_name
```

I get the following error

```
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format
```

I googled a lot but I am not sure if any of the solutions could help me. I have to use my old certificate and cannot use a new one because I can't upload it then to playstore.

What do I have to do that it works again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like the error says, you have an issue with the format of your keystore.  Check the `-keystore` argument in your `jarsigner` command line op. It's an `.apk` file when it should be your `.keystore` file.

Do like this:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was very stupid :D
So easy and I wouldn't have found my error on myself because it's just too dumb

Comment: You're not dumb, it happens to all of us! I'm glad it's working now.